# MySQL group data under custom column name

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I would like that data as in table below:

```
Failed | Passed
1         1
```

Instead having this column header names i would like to change it to, and is this possible?

```
Status | Count
Failed    1
Passed    1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: This is called pivot table. The duplicate topic describes both static  (number of columns is know in advance) and dynamic pivoting (number of columns not know in advance).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of COUNT use SUM to sum over the values you need, like the folowing

```
SELECT SUM(status='Failed') as failed, SUM(status='Passed') 
FROM table_with_status
```

This works because when you write status='Failed'  it returns 1 if status is failed, and otherwise it returns zero